# Google Test: Parameterized tests which use an existing test fixture class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a test fixture class which is currently used by many tests.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
class MyFixtureTest : public ::testing::Test {
  void SetUp() { ... }
};
```

I would like to create a parameterized test which also uses all that MyFixtureTest has to offer, without needing to change all my existing tests.

How do I do that?

I have found similar discussions on the web, but have not fully understood their answers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that for regular tests your fixture has to be derived from testing::Test and for parameterized tests, it has to be derived from testing::TestWithParam<>.

In order to accommodate that, you'll have to modify your fixture class in order to work with your parameter type

```
template <class T> class MyFixtureBase : public T {
  void SetUp() { ... };
  // Put the rest of your original MyFixtureTest here.
};

// This will work with your non-parameterized tests.
class MyFixtureTest : public MyFixtureBase<testing::Test> {};

// This will be the fixture for all your parameterized tests.
// Just substitute the actual type of your parameters for MyParameterType.
class MyParamFixtureTest : public MyFixtureBase<
    testing::TestWithParam<MyParameterType> > {};
```

This way you can keep all your existing tests intact while creating parameterized tests using

```
TEST_P(MyParamFixtureTest, MyTestName) { ... }
```

Comment: Had to go with this solution since I have a really old version of gtest that does't support WithParamInterface;

Answer (score 56):

This question is now answered in the [Google Test documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests) (the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250880/334142) from VladLosev is technically correct, but perhaps slightly more work)

Specifically, when you want to add parameters to a pre-existing fixture class, you can do

```
class MyFixtureTest : public ::testing::Test {
  ...
};
class MyParamFixtureTest : public MyFixtureTest,
                           public ::testing::WithParamInterface<MyParameterType> {
  ...
};

TEST_P(MyParamFixtureTest, MyTestName) { ... }
```

Comment: This definitely seems cleaner and less work compared to what VladLosev proposed (which is technically correct and perhaps from a time when the ParamInterface was not available)

Comment: Don't forget that if you define `SetUp()` in `MyParamFixtureTest` it should call `MyFixtureTest::SetUp()`, otherwise that setup of the base class will never run.

Comment: How do I instantiate `MyParamFixtureTest` with the right parameter of type `MyParameterType` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new fixture that is derived from this common one and than create your parameterized tests on that derived class - would that help you and solve your problem?

From Google Test [wiki page](https://google.github.io/googletest/faq.html#can-i-derive-a-test-fixture-from-another):

> In Google Test, you share a fixture among test cases by putting the shared logic in a base test fixture, then deriving from that base a separate fixture for each test case that wants to use this common logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My issue is that a parameterized test fixture needs to inherit from ::testing::TestWithParam, whereas my current fixture only inherits from ::testing::Test. Also, tests which use parameterized tests are declared with TEST_P instead of TEST_F. Any ideas how to resolve the differences?