# passing different parameters to testFixture constructor

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a question about google tests. My scenario is as below

```
class GeneralTest public ::testing::Test
{

public:
   GeneralTest(const std::string filename, const int number) 
   {

   }

};


class MyTest : public GeneralTest
{

public:
    MyTest(const std::string &filename, const int number) : GeneralTest(filename, number)
    {

    }

    MyTest(const std::string &filename): MyTest(filename, 55) {};

protected:
  std::string m_filename;

};
```

My requirement is that I want to pass different filenames for different tests. When the text fixture is passed to the test case constructor is allready called (I assume). How can I cleanly do it in such a way that I get control over what filename to pass

Comment: Do you mean, hard-coded, but different, filenames?

Comment: I was thinking 'parameterized tests' immediately, and look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250880/6610

Comment: @xtofl - yes I do mean hardcoded but different file names

Comment: Then think https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118760/6610 shows you a valid answer, doesn't it?  (it refers to parameterized tests: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests)

Comment: @xtofl - I saw the answer. though helpful, I am not sure how to `instantiate MyParamFixtureTest with the right parameter of type MyParameterType ` ? could you please guide

Comment: your parameter type will be an `std::string` or a `const char *`.  Did you find the section about `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P`?